# Finding Timestamp pattern from a String

Tags: java, timestamp

I want to convert a String into Timestamp, the pattern for which is unknown. Is there any API given by java which allows us to feed in the string and returns the possible patterns that could work with it? I understand that one could have some pre-defined patterns against which the String can be parsed and checked. But, since this is a timestamp, the number combinations of different dates and times will be quite a lot. So, was looking for an efficient way of figuring out the pattern of the String-Timestamp.

Comment: one small example: how is 03.04.2011 going to be treated? as MM/dd/yyyy or dd/MM/yyyy? Or do you want a method to return both for example as possible patterns for the timestamp?

Comment: I was thinking of getting possible outcomes and further process it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Never heard about ready-to-use library for something like this, as @Eugene noted, possible combinations for all the patterns is huge so there is probably no such a library. 
I would recommend rethinking your architecture.

If you just want to play with something like this you can create your own implementation.
Lets say that you parse the input and then you figure out the array of integers 
`(09, 21, 12, 0, 44, 33)`
, you can assume that the array contains year, day, month, minute, hour and seconds (not sure if you can assume that - its just an example)

Once you have that array you can create all possible permutations of this array - [example here](http://cs.fit.edu/~ryan/java/programs/combinations/Permute-java.html)

Then you can create a Date object for each combination:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(09, 12, 21, 0, 44, 33, 0);
```

(above example is for [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/quickstart.html))

If you know for example that the year value will always be sent with 4 characters then possible number of combinations will decrease of course, further you can assume that '26' will not be the value for the month etc.. you probably get the idea.

Comment: Yes, this could be one approach. But I believe there will be a lot of code trying to figure out the right pattern / s using this approach.

Answer (score 0):

In this case , first I would switch to Joda Time : http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Then I would generate some (try to decrease the possibilities as much as you can, as there are way too many) the Patterns and try the date over them. If it does not throw an error (aka it fits, put it in an array), then return the array. This is probably a very non-optimized solution, but this is where I would start.

I really do not think that there are libraries for that. Also, you might want to explain why you want to do that. may be the solution is a bit simpler.

Cheers,
Eugene.

Comment: I am doing this already, have a pre-defined hashmap with few formats in it which I cross check against the incoming string. Why do I want to do it? Coz the data comes in text format without any information about the format.

Comment: @akkyy I think this is the best you can do right now. You should though do some minor tricking like see what is the most used Pattern and check against that(those) first, then you could probably massage the data a bit to see may be it does not fit some formats very fast...